# Can you generalize vieta's theorem for the case of quadratic equation having one root?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$x^2+bx+c=0.$ The sum of roots formula checks out since discriminant is 0. But the product of roots is $\frac{b^2}{4}$ not c. Help.

Comment: If that quadratic equation has one root, $b^2-4c=0$...

Comment: True. Silly mistake never mind. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, simply if $x^2+bx+c=0$ has one root then $$\Delta=0 \implies b^2-4c=0\implies b^2=4c\implies c=\frac{b^2}{4}.$$

So it is $c$ after all.